# JavaScript: Переход при клике по строке таблицы

Tags: javascript

Имеется таблица, которая генерируется посредством `ASP.NET`:

```
<asp:Repeater ItemType="..." SelectMethod="..." runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="table" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#DDD'"
            onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white'" onclick="location.href='/item/<%#: Item.Id %>'">
            <td><%#: Item.Id %></td>
            <td><%#: Item.... %></td>
            <td><%#: Item.... %></td>
            <td><%#: Item.... %></td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="/item/<%#: Item.Id %>">Открыть</a></td>
                            <td><a href="/blank/<%#: Item.Id %>" target="_blank">Печать</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>                            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

С помощью `JavaScript` здесь реализован переход по ссылке при клике в любом месте строки, всё работает как надо за исключением последнего столбца.

В последнем столбце таблицы есть отдельная ссылка для печати бланка, бланк открывается в новой вкладке. Бланк открывается нормально, но при этом в текущей вкладке выполняется переход по ссылке из `JS`. Как убрать действие `JS` для последнего столбца таблицы?

Comment: если честно - за такое надо наказывать, это просто не знание HTML5 и CSS3. вставлять таблицу в ячейку таблицы. и где такому научили?

Comment: @Вадим, спасибо за замечание. Действительно, я десктоп-разработчик, и web не знаю вообще. Но есть задача и надо её решить, поэтому приходится сочинять на ходу и гуглить решения. А таблица в таблице... Ну с точки зрения, например, десктоп разработки с использованием XAML/WPF, Grid в grid'е - вполне себе годное решение, да и проще сопровождается чем один монструозный Grid...

Comment: тогда следует ознакомиться https://learn.javascript.ru/ , http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/ , https://webref.ru/css , https://webref.ru/html , http://shpargalkablog.ru/p/html-css-javascript.html , http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#DDD'"
            onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white'"
для этого существует hover

Comment: @Вадим, поделитесь примером использования :hover, который бы выделял цветом всю строку таблицы, а не отдельную ячейку. Спасибо!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n6gvcrqo/

Comment: загляни ещё https://jsfiddle.net/n6gvcrqo/1/ там вариант с тегами <a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие `click` всплывает до `tr` родительской таблицы, где выполняется его обработчик.

```
<td>
  <a href="/blank/<%#: Item.Id %>" target="_blank" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">Печать</a>
</td>
```